# Ctags in a Rails/Vim project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I am building my Rails projects with Vim but I have had a horrible experience switching files.  I have been reading about Ctags and I think this may help me have a better experience.

The problem is that I see so many different opinions on the configuration of Ctags and I'm not sure what to do.  I also don't want to manually run a command every time files change so the index can be refreshed.

Is there a standard in the Rails community of Vim plugins for Ctags?

Comment: I don't know about Rails in particular, but personally, I run Ctags on every commit and update with a VCS hook.

Answer (score 1):

For rails development I suggest you use [rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails). It provides a `:Ctags` command. See `:h rails-:Ctags`.

Look into some tagging plugins like [Gutentags](https://github.com/ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags) or [vim-easytags](https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags)

Comment: fugitive.vim no longer set vim/neovim to look for tags in .git/tags. It is mentioned [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/1486#issuecomment-594679342) by Tim Pope.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out `vim-easytags`

https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags

> Automated tag generation and syntax highlighting in Vim